# Remove/Merge Duplicate ID in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Good Evening,

Following Code:

```
    Dim RunningNum As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim MaskType As String
    Dim CurWkSt As Worksheet
    
    Set CurWkSt = Sheets("Output")
    
    LastRow = Sheets("Imported").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    'For Loop to add all information,if duplicated Employee Number.
    
    For RunningNum = 3 To LastRow
        CurWkSt.Range("A" & RunningNum & ":AI" & RunningNum).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        CurWkSt.Range("A" & RunningNum & ":AI" & RunningNum).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        'If Current Employee Number matches Previous Employee Number
        If CurWkSt.Range("E" & RunningNum) = CurWkSt.Range("E" & RunningNum - 1) Then
    
            'Highlight Employee ID Column to let you visually know.
            CurWkSt.Cells(RunningNum, 5).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            
            'Find Which Mask it was previously and add to previous row!
            If Not IsEmpty(CurWkSt.Range("J" & RunningNum)) Then
                CurWkSt.Range("J" & RunningNum - 1).Value = CurWkSt.Range("J" & RunningNum).Value
                CurWkSt.Range("J" & RunningNum - 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 102, 255)
                CurWkSt.Range("T" & RunningNum - 1).Value = CurWkSt.Range("T" & RunningNum).Value
            End If
    
            If Not IsEmpty(CurWkSt.Range("K" & RunningNum)) Then
                CurWkSt.Range("K" & RunningNum - 1).Value = CurWkSt.Range("K" & RunningNum).Value
                CurWkSt.Range("K" & RunningNum - 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 204, 255)
                CurWkSt.Range("U" & RunningNum - 1).Value = CurWkSt.Range("U" & RunningNum).Value
            End If
            
            If Not IsEmpty(CurWkSt.Range("L" & RunningNum)) Then
                CurWkSt.Range("L" & RunningNum - 1).Value = CurWkSt.Range("L" & RunningNum).Value
                CurWkSt.Range("L" & RunningNum - 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 204, 0)
                CurWkSt.Range("V" & RunningNum - 1).Value = CurWkSt.Range("V" & RunningNum).Value
            End If
            
            If Not IsEmpty(CurWkSt.Range("M" & RunningNum)) Then
                CurWkSt.Range("M" & RunningNum - 1).Value = CurWkSt.Range("M" & RunningNum).Value
                CurWkSt.Range("M" & RunningNum - 1).Interior.Color = RGB(204, 236, 255)
                CurWkSt.Range("W" & RunningNum - 1).Value = CurWkSt.Range("W" & RunningNum).Value
            End If
            
            If Not IsEmpty(CurWkSt.Range("N" & RunningNum)) Then
                CurWkSt.Range("N" & RunningNum - 1).Value = CurWkSt.Range("N" & RunningNum).Value
                CurWkSt.Range("N" & RunningNum - 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 230, 153)
                CurWkSt.Range("X" & RunningNum - 1).Value = CurWkSt.Range("X" & RunningNum).Value
            End If
            
            If Not IsEmpty(CurWkSt.Range("O" & RunningNum)) Then
                CurWkSt.Range("O" & RunningNum - 1).Value = CurWkSt.Range("O" & RunningNum).Value
                CurWkSt.Range("O" & RunningNum - 1).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
                CurWkSt.Range("Y" & RunningNum - 1).Value = CurWkSt.Range("Y" & RunningNum).Value
            End If
            
            If Not IsEmpty(CurWkSt.Range("P" & RunningNum)) Then
                CurWkSt.Range("P" & RunningNum - 1).Value = CurWkSt.Range("P" & RunningNum).Value
                CurWkSt.Range("P" & RunningNum - 1).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
                CurWkSt.Range("Z" & RunningNum - 1).Value = CurWkSt.Range("Z" & RunningNum).Value
            End If
            'For now, we will hide the Duplicated Lines.
            'CurWkSt.Rows(RunningNum).Hidden = True
            'When in operation, we can delete these lines
            CurWkSt.Rows(RunningNum).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
    
    Call AddTotals
End Sub
```

It works currently, but the problem I've got now, and I'm unsure why!

Lets say for example row's were

```
1| 12345 | other stuff
2| 12345 | other stuff
3| 12345 | other stuff
4| 12345 | other stuff
```

Its only removing the second line, and adding it to the first, but not doing it to any other lines. Example:

```
1| 12345 | other stuff | Other stuff
3| 12345 | other stuff
4| 12345 | other stuff
```

but not adding all the others together.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this? My first thought was to run the sub multiple times, but that's stupid!

Comment: When you delete rows always start from the last one and move up. (`For RunningNum = LastRow To 3 Step -1`

Comment: @BrakNicku, thanks so much mate! I got it working from your comment! Appreciate the help mate!